# C# dictionary store action/method

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary with `string` keys, e.g. `123456789`. Now at some other point inside my application, I want my dictionary to look this key up and either run the method itself (stored along the key) or somehow return the function so I can manually add parameters. Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes. Why would it not be possible?

Comment: Yes, quite simple actually. You can make the type of the value any delegate you want (e.g. `Action`, `Predicate`, etc.).

Comment: Why would it not be possible to disable gravity? @Cal279

Comment: I thought of `Action<>`, but wondered if this is the right point to get this one started.

Comment: Because science is not that far yet. But lucky you - what you want is possible.

Comment: Have a look at reflection

Comment: Yes, `Action<>` can be stored within a dictionary. Upon retrieval you can execute it like a regular function, e.g. `dict["123"](parameter)`

Comment: @illug Always a good topic, but seems like overkill in this particular situation.

Comment: Thanks, @ManfredRadlwimmer. I'll take a look at this.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a `dictionary<string, Action>`, this would be for no parameters.

e.g.

```
static class MyActions {
  static Dictionary<string,Action> wibble = new Dictionary<string,Action>();
}
```

I've used static, its not necessary if you can pass the reference around/retrieve the reference.

then to add action...

```
MyActions.wibble["123456789"] = () => { // do action };
```

or reference a no parameter method

```
MyActions.wibble["123456789"] = () => MyMethod;
```

then to call it;

```
MyActions.wibble["123456789"]()
```

Assuming the key exists, you can use try get or even `MyActions.wibble["123456789"]?.Invoke()`

If you need parameters, make the dictionary of type `Action<T>` or `Action<T1, T2>` etc depending on the number of parameters.

eg `wibble = new Dictionary<string,Action<int>>()`

and then `wibble["123456789"] = x => {action with x}`

and `wibble["123456789"](42)`

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a simple task. (Doesn't include sanity checks)

```
Dictionary<string,Action<object>> dict;

public Action<object> GetFunction(string key)
{
    return dict[key];
}

public void CallFunction(string key, object parameter)
{
    dict[key](parameter);
}
```